# Struts2 package namespace inheriting

Tags: struts2

```
<package name="A" extends="default" namespace="/A">
    ...
</package>
<package name="B" extends="A" namespace="/B">
    <action name="show" class="...">
        ...
    </action>
</package>
```

In the above setup, I wonder why the namespace isn't inherited in package **B** so that I can invoke the action **show** with namespace `/A/B/show`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not how it works; no other reason.

This is discussed in [the docs](http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/namespace-configuration.html):

> Namespace are not hierarchical like a file system path. There is one namespace level.

Comment: I see. I guess it kind of makes sense.

Comment: @Will *shrug* I've never been sure if it makes sense or not; it's likely too late to change it now, though. I'll think about it.

Comment: I feel struts2 isn't meant to be used for rest service so what's point of implementing rest style url with it?

Comment: @Will That's what the REST plugin is for, but it doesn't have strong support for nested resources. Although using normal JSON serialization and routing it's easy enough, just not as automatic as might be nice.